# Setting the [field] of <p-autocomplete/> manually

Tags: angular, primeng, form-control

I am using `p-autocomplete` in my template:

```
<p-autoComplete [suggestions]="complexObjects" [formControl]="inputFormControl" [dropdown]="true" [multiple]="multiple"
        
            (onSelect)="onSelect($event)">

    </p-autoComplete>
```

`[suggestions]="complexObjects"` is an array of complex objects such as:

```
[{
    "name": {
        "value": 4,
        "lang": {
            "language": {
                "value": "en"
            },
            "field1": "Pakistan",
            "field2": "Pakistan",
            "field3": "Pakistan"
        }
    }
}]
```

Here's what on `(onSelect)="onSelect($event)"` does:

```
 selectedValues: string[] = [];

 onSelect(event: any) {

    this.selectedValues.push(event.name.value);
    this.inputFormControl.setValue(this.selectedValues);

  }
```

Is there a way to set the `[field]` for `p-autocomplete` "manually"? What I want to do is set `field1` from `complexObjects` as the `[field]` value, but I don't want to save the whole object to the `inputFormControl.values`.

All I can find from the documentation is the [field] attribute:

Here's pseudocode of what I would like to do:

```
<p-autoComplete [field]="getField()"/>

getField():string{
return complexObjects.name.lang.field1;
}
```

https://primeng.org/autocomplete

Comment: field prop is used for showing suggestions, is a property from the objects list passed as data source for the autocomplete. Do you want to see suggestions by accessing those objects field1 prop, but when option is selected, input value to not be the whole object? if yes, what do you want to be?

Comment: What I am trying to do is set the name as in:

https://primeng.org/autocomplete#multiple


After you select a country and it shows up as a green "button". That's the field I want to set manually.

Comment: I think you could do this with another fomrcontrol, and this will be the one of interest, and every type when autocomplete fc changes, set value of this, and before of this do the necessary transformations.